# Complicated Recursive function - Distributing stars among rooms and people

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

Lets say I have a total number of stars n, there are rooms and each room contains maximum 3 people. I want to know how many combinations I can distribute the stars knowing that one person can have maximum 7 stars.

For example, I have 4 stars in total. One possible solution would be:

```
room: person *
room: person *
room: person *
room: person *

another possible is
room: person ****

another just in case is
room: person* person* person*
room: person *

public class SolutionData
{
        public class PackData
        {
            public List< int > people; // number of stars
            public PackData( )
            {
                people= new List<int>( );
            }
        }

        public List< PackData > packs;

        public SolutionData( )
        {
            packs = new List< PackData >( );
        }
}
```

Is there any way I can fill an array of solutionData containing all the possiblities?

What I have

```
static void GetSolutions( int totalRank , ref List< SolutionData > solutions )
{
    if( totalRank == 0 ) return;

    if( totalRank >= 1 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 1 , ref solutions );
    if( totalRank >= 2 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 2 , ref solutions );
    if( totalRank >= 3 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 3 , ref solutions );
    if( totalRank >= 4 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 4 , ref solutions );
    if( totalRank >= 5 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 5 , ref solutions );
    if( totalRank >= 6 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 6 , ref solutions );
    if( totalRank >= 7 ) GetSolutions( totalRank - 7 , ref solutions );
}
```

At some point I have to fill the solution but I really don't know where and how. I don't even know if part of the function is correct.

NOTES: There is not limit of room/packs, obviously the maximum number is the total stars n. Total stars n is not going to be something very high, maximum 20-30.

Comment: That's a math question, ask it on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: so what have you tried? I think the usual brute-force recursive algorithm should be not too hard (of course this is most probably some coding-game exercise so this will fail) - the next thing to try would be DP ...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski it's not - things like this are very common in code interviews and things like hacker-earth, code_eval, ...

Comment: Agree with @LucasTrzesniewski this question is about Combinatorics, and solving it using bruteforce recursion is kinda bad, M'kay.

Comment: @Carsten its not a test, it's something I'm doing for myself. I've edited with  what I have, which is probably not much.

Comment: @marcg11 how big will your total number of stars get? because for small(ish) values a variant using LINQ would not be to bad

Comment: @Carsten will not be more than 50 for sure maximum 30ish

Comment: 50 is to big for brute force - do you know anything about dynamic programming?

Comment: @Carsten No, never heard about it. Will brute force be to much time? I mean, as long it's not minutes, but 2 seconds it can wait.

Comment: I think we are talking about hours if not days or weeks here ;) - for brute force you would enumerate all possibilities and that's really ... really a lot (btw. your numbers will never fit Int32 or something ;)

Comment: here is a quick run for small numbers: `n=5->73`, `n=10->12752` and `n=15->2233334` ... now imagine 30 or 50 ;)

Comment: Are those seconds? :O

Comment: no those are the combinations a simple brute-force algorithm produced (caution for this different permutations are counted each) ... I don't want to guess the runtime

Comment: This problem is underspecified. Can we assume as a condition of the problem that all persons must have at least one star? Do the people have identity? Do the rooms have identity?  That is, is "Bob has one star in the library and Jill has one star in the kitchen" is the same as or different than "Bob has one star in the kitchen and Jill has one star in the library"?  That makes a huge difference in the number of combinations.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can fill an array of solutionData containing all the possiblities?

I wouldn't go with this approach. If the goal is to create the set of combinations then *return a set of combinations*. Don't take an array and fill it in. What goes in the method? The number of stars. What comes out? The set of combinations. The method should have the signature:

```
static IEnumerable<SolutionData> GetSolutions(int totalRank)
```

You wish to create a recursive solution, and you have the sketch of a recursive solution:

- You have a trivial base case.  You seem to have a solution for zero stars -- that is, there are no solutions -- but that might not be that helpful. *Given the solution for zero stars, can you construct the solution for one star*? That's what you need to do. If you can't do that then the base case has to be one star, not zero.
- A recursive case that simplifies to a smaller problem. Suppose you seek a solution for 10 stars, **and you already have a solution for 9 stars**.  Can you use the solution for 9 stars to construct the solution for 10 stars? If not, then the algorithm is not going to be recursive. Now generalize it; if you have a solution for n-1 stars, can you create a solution *from that information* that solves the problem for n stars?

So your method will have the form:

```
if (in the base case)
    return the trivial solution
else
    solve a smaller problem recursively
    construct the solution to the larger problem from that solution
    return the solution
```

Where you seem to be falling down here is in generating new solutions given the solutions to smaller problems. Concentrate on that. Suppose you wished to solve the problem for 10, and here, I'll magically give you the solution for 9. How would you use that information to advantage?

Now, once you have that it might be too slow to be feasible. A comment mentions dynamic programming, which is the following technique:

```
if (in the base case)
    return the trivial solution
else if (we have solved this problem before and remember the solution)
     return the previous solution
else
    solve a smaller problem recursively
    construct the solution to the larger problem from that solution
    make a note in global state of the solution to this problem
    return the solution
```

The idea of dynamic programming is that many recursive algorithms spend a lot of time re-solving problems they already solved a few nanoseconds ago. If you burn the extra memory to remember the solutions you can save on the time of recomputing them.

Comment: Why don't you think 0 stars would make a good base case?  I'd expect the recursive case to be essentially, "Find the solutions for n-1 stars, and then find all solutions where you give one of your stars to one person for each combination".  Thus if your base case is one star, then both the base case and recursive case are duplicating the logic of, "give a single star to one person".  If the base case is zero, it can just return the set of people with no added stars (a trivial task, as one hopes in a base case).  Then the n=1 case is solve n=0 and give one person a star.

Comment: @Servy: I haven't given the actual problem a lot of thought. Your conjecture seems plausible.